# После транзакции с робокассы переход на определенный урл

Tags: python, django, робокасса

К Django-проекту подключены Робокасса и Яндекс касса. Возможно ли программно отдавать url в робокассу(яндекс кассу) так, чтобы при успешной транзакции пользователя перебрасывало именно на этот success url

Например, человек перешёл в робокассу после того, как побывал на определенной странице, хотелось бы, чтобы после успешной оплаты он попадал туда же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для Яндекс.Кассы необходимо передать в платежную форму "**PaymentForm**" 2 параметра:

```
shopFailURL = 'url'
shopSuccessURL = 'url'
```

Они представляют собой URLField.
Их также можно передать скрытыми полями внутри шаблона:

```
<input hidden name="shopFailURL" value="сюда_ссылку">
<input hidden name="shopSuccessURL" value="сюда_ссылку">
```

Для робокассы. Переопределяем в классовом представлении формы Робокассы:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    request.session['next'] = self.request.get_full_path()
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Делаем вьюху, в которую будем переходить при Success'e формы:

```
class SuccessRobokassaView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'next' in request.session:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.session['next'])
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

Добавляем эту вьюху к списку URL'ов:

```
path('success_url/', SuccessRobokassaView.as_view(), name='success-robokassa'),
```

В личном кабинете Робокассы направляем Success URL на нашу новую ссылку.

Comment: в сессию можно положить урл

Comment: Да, действительно. Совсем забыл про сессию. Обновил.

Comment: Я это к тому чтоб сделать единый способ для яндекса и робокассы